# MySQL client 8.0.35 / server 5.1 ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bob'@'hostname.com' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql

I'm provisioning a new Ubuntu 22.04 machine and I'm unable to get the MySQL 8.0.35 client to connect to the 5.1.58 server.  Until recently, I had been using 8.0.34 and had been unable to connect due to the "bad handshake" bug that was fixed in 8.0.35.  Now that that's been fixed, I'm getting this error:

```
% mysql -V
mysql  Ver 8.0.35-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
% mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bob'@'hostname.com' (using password: NO)
% mysql -u bob -h mysqlserver.hostname.com --port 3306 -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bob'@'hostname.com' (using password: NO)
```

I've looked for posts discussing "access denied" problems, but I haven't found any that are relevant; most discuss problems when "using password: YES" or when trying to use mysql as root with no password.  However, I am in fact using the password, so it seems quite suspicious that the message says "using password: NO"

If I downgrade to MySQL 5.7.42 client, I am able to connect just fine, either providing my password on the command line, or leaving it in my $HOME/.my.cnf file, so I'm pretty sure it's not a permissions problem on the server side.  I've had other users try, and they get the same error.

```
% mysql
[..]
Server version: 5.1.58-log Source distribution
[..]
mysql>
```

Upgrading the server right now is not an option, not for at least 6 months or so, and it's beyond my control anyway since I don't have access to the server machine.

I presume, from the fact that the "bad handshake" bug was fixed (https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=90994), that this is at least supposed to work, even though 5.1 is well past EOL.

Is there perhaps some setting I need to add in .my.cnf to get the 8.0 client to talk to the 5.1 server?  Is there a way to diagnose this problem without having IT restart the server in debug mode?  Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt compatibility testing between mysql current and mysql-server-ancient is performed.

You can packet capture the protocol to see what's going on and Wireshark will annotate it nicely. Compare to [protocol documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/latest/page_protocol_connection_phase.html).

The [command line](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html) options are limited in controlling the protocol.

Sounds most productive to just stick with your old mysql-5.7 client now (or a MariaDB one will likely also work).

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem right now. Remote server is running 5.1.73. Fresh lubuntu installation is mysql 8.0.36.

No matter if i put a pass in the command line, or just "-p" to provide a pass. Always auth fail with "using password NO" when try to connect to a remote server. Error 1045 (28000)

I have Navicat gui and works fine, local and remote. I installed lubuntu and tried mysql workbench and found this weird situation.

I can connect to my local server with mysql/mysql-workbench and if i provide a wrong pass, says "using password : YES), when blank, says "using password : NO". Seems ok. But when try to connect to old mysql remote server, always "using password : NO".

I need to run some bash scripts invoking mysql and mysqldump...and at the end of the day, downgraded to old mysql version...